# Why does Velocity lose session after only a few minutes?

Tags: asp.net, session, appfabric, distributed-caching

I've set up sesion management with Velocity distributed cache. I have 3 servers hosting the cache and created the named cache with

```
new-cache Sessions -Secondaries 1 TTL 1440
```

and the following is in my web.config file

```
<section name="dataCacheClient"
type="Microsoft.Data.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,&#xD;&#xA;   cacheBaseLibrary"
allowLocation="true"
allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>

    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="Velocity" >
        <providers>
            <add
              name="Velocity"
                       type="Microsoft.Data.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider"
              cacheName="Sessions"/>
        </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ites are getting evicted. By default caches are evictable, i.e, items stored in the cache can be evicted. You should create a non-evictable cache using the new-cache command.
Example:
New-Cache  -Eviction None

Set other cache properties as is required.